# reprepro complains about the generated pbuilder debian.tar.gz archive md5

Tags: md5, apt, pbuilder

I have configured a private APT repository (using resources on internet like http://inodes.org/2009/09/14/building-a-private-ppa-on-ubuntu/) and I'm uploading for the first time my package containing the sources of my C++ application.
So reprepro repository is empty.

I use the following command in order to start the build:

```
sudo reprepro -V -b /srv/reprepro processincoming incoming
```

Then the build start, a lot of output is genearated and I can see that `pbuilder` is compiling the project source code and everything is fine. I can even find in the `result/` folder debian packages etc...

But the build failed with a **POST_BUILD_FAILED** because it seems that pbuilder has changed the **douane-testing_0.8.1-apt1.debian.tar.gz** file and the md5 sum is now different as shown here:

```
File "pool/main/d/douane-testing/douane-testing_0.8.1-apt1.debian.tar.gz" is already registered with different checksums!
md5 expected: 97257ae2c5790b84ed7bb1b412f1d518, got: df78f88b97cadc10bc0a73bf86442838
sha1 expected: ae93c44593e821696f72bee4d91ce4b6f261e529, got: d6f910ca5707ec92cb71601a4f4c72db0e5f18d9
sha256 expected: c3fac5ed112f89a8ed8d4137b34f173990d8a4b82b6212d1e0ada1cddc869b0e, got: ebdcc9ead44ea0dd99f2dc87decffcc5e3efaee64a8f62f54aec556ac19d579c
size expected: 2334, got: 2344
There have been errors!
```

I don't understand why it is failing as when I compare the 2 packages (having those md5 sums) the content is strictly the same (I used a diff tool but no differences and no new or removed files).
The only thing I can see is that the archive from pbuild is bigger of 10 Bytes than the orginal one I have uploaded:

On my development machine, the file with the md5 **97257ae2c5790b84ed7bb1b412f1d518** :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 zedtux zedtux   2334 Feb  3 23:38 douane-testing_0.8.1-apt1.debian.tar.gz
```

On my server, the file with the md5 **df78f88b97cadc10bc0a73bf86442838** :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2344 Feb  5 00:58 douane-testing_0.8.1-apt1.debian.tar.gz
```

I have pbuild version 0.213 on my server.

What could be the reason of this behavior and how can I fix it ?

**Edit**

I'm suspecting an issue with the GPG key which looks missing and then files aren't signed so md5sum is different.
During the build process I have the following lines:

```
I: Extracting source
gpgv: Signature made Wed Feb  5 22:04:37 2014 UTC using RSA key ID 9474CF36
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./douane-testing_0.8.1-apt1.dsc
```

**Edit 2**

I have tried to find the command to create manually the .debian.tar.gz file.
The best I've found is the following:

```
tar cv debian | gzip --no-name --rsyncable -9 > douane-testing_0.8.1-apt1.debian.tar.gz
```

I don't get the same result than `dpkg-source` but I tried the same command on my server (I should at least have the same size) but it's not matching...

Could it be that Debian and Ubuntu aren't compressing the same way ?

Comment: I have tried to upload my package without signature (so the warning is gone) but the md5 issue is still here... so it's not that the issue...

Comment: It's like the way to compress the debian/ folder is not the same on my development machine and my server...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My previous answer is alright but is not complete.

Then I had the issue that reprepro complains about the source tarball (.orig.tar.xz).
But it was normal as I wasn't doing the packages correctly.

I have written a bash script which I'm executing in VM for each Ubuntu series.
This script was always doing everything from scratch, and was using dh_make --createorig argument and here is the issue.

The correct way is to generate once (for example on Ubuntu precise) and then re-use the .orig.tar.xz file and no more use the --createorig argument of dh_make.

I hope this could help someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally after some evenings of research I found the solution on [launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pbuilder/+bug/118180) !

> Found the solution. By default pbuilder calls dpkg-buildpackage like so:
>
> DEBBUILDOPTS="$DEBBUILDOPTS -rfakeroot"
>   dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc $DEBBUILDOPTS
>
> That causes dpkg-buildpackage to rebuild the diff.gz and .dsc files. Add a -b in there, and it won't. It also means the resulting .changes file will only reference the .deb file. Which is what you want, I think.
>
> The easy solution is to add a line to your .pbuilderrc:
>
> DEBBUILDOPTS="-b"